# Localize actions in resource urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The Rails router has a brilliant option to localize a particular resource by using the `path` option.

E.g.

```
resources :clients, path: 'kunder' # Danish for clients.
```

Unfortunately, this still produces a URL like

```
/kunder/new
```

or

```
/kunder/7913/edit
```

instead of  `ny` and `rediger`, which would be correct Danish.

How can I get around this, while still using the terse `resources` syntax?

Comment: There are present a very nice gem `route_translator`. Check it out: https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator. I think it will be very helpful for you.